# Pushing changes commited by someone else

Tags: git

My friend commited some changes but didn't push them to the repository. Now I want to push this commit to "development" branch. How could I do this?

I mean, cloning the repo and doing the checkout to development branch would create a local repo for me, I wouldn't see the unpushed commit.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is equivalent to "My friend wrote a Word document for me, and saved it on his local machine. He didn't upload it to the server, or sent it to anyone. How can I get it?"

Like the analogous question, the answer is "you can't", your friend will have to push changes with `git push REMOTE BRANCH`, and then you'll be able to get them with `git clone` or `git pull` (if you already have the repo cloned).

Comment: But if I see the commit on bitbucket, then I guessed I can somehow get it also locally.

Comment: If you see the commit on bitbucket, that means that your coworker *did* push the commits to the repository. So you should be able to get it in the normal means (`git pull REMOTE BRANCH`) so that they're available locally. If you want to add the commit to a different branch, read about `git merge` and `git cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your friend shares the commits to you, via patches, git-bundles, some public online repo like one hosted in Github, a copy of his/her .git in a portable disk or ftp, ssh access to your computer or the other direction, and etc.
2. You apply the commits into your local branch.
3. You push your local branch to the remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

you have two option one is make your friend to commit the repository or
have his gitlab account and login it.then copy the changes in his repository then go to your local repository and save it.

```
add.
commit -m
```

this wiil do

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

Tell your friend to

- push the commit
- give you access to his repository, add it to your remotes, fetch his commits and then push it
- provide you a patch, apply it, make a new commit and push it. Your friend must then rebase his history when he fetches the next time.